# install4j rpm media file ignores service and zip file actions

Tags: rpm, install4j

I'm trying to generate an rpm media file using install4j multi platform v5.0.8.
My launcher executable is "Service".
My installer includes the ""Install a service" action.
When I'm installing the rpm, the root directory and the script that runs the application are created successfully. However, no link is placed in /etc/init.d.
I tried using rpm -ivv to investigate the matter, and it seems that no command to add the link is issued.

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPM archive will not execute any actions. Only installers execute screens and actions. You have to define a Unix/Linux GUI installer for that on the "Media" step of the install4j IDE.

Comment: You are right! What confused me was that I had a "Create program group" action which is meant to create a link in /usr/local/bin, and the rpm added this link. I now checked, and the link is added even when the action is disabled.